# Angular Ionic Checkbox model not updating

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have weird problem now In my modal component I have below checkboxes

```
<ion-list>
  <h3 class="head">Ayarlar</h3>
  <ion-item >
    <ion-label>İsimlerin çoğul halini de tahmin et</ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox slot="end"(ionChange)="setSetting()" [(ngModel)]="setting.IsPlural"></ion-checkbox>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item >
    <ion-label>Fillerin çekim halini de tahmin et</ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox slot="end"(ionChange)="setSetting()" [(ngModel)]="setting.IsConjugated"></ion-checkbox>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

and in component

```
 setting: Setting;
 setSetting(){
    console.log(this.setting);
  }
```

and my Setting class is

```
export class Setting {
  public IsPlural: boolean = false;
  public IsConjugated: boolean = false;
  constructor() {}
}
```

so when I check checkbox ngmodel not updating setting class values they are always false even I check or not. I don't have any idea why happens like that. How can I solve this problem ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could get the new value from ionChange event directly:
Html part:

```
<ion-checkbox slot="end"(ionChange)="setSetting($event)" [(ngModel)]="setting.IsPlural"></ion-checkbox>
```

Typescript part:

```
setSetting(data:any){
let newValue = data.details.value;
console.log(newValue);
}
```